# Excel Failed to Refresh the Query and throws an error irrespective of the code being proper

Tags: excel, vba

I have a query to refresh excel. But somehow it is not working. Just for information it is not a connection it is a query that is to be refreshed. I have used the following code.

```
FldrM = "C:\XYZ"
ReportFormat = "C:\Report.xlsx" 
Mdate = DatePart("M" , Now)
Mdate = Right("0" & Mdate, 2)
DayDate=DatePart("D", Now)
DayDate= Right("0" & DayDate, 2)
Tdate = DatePart("YYYY" , Now) & Right("0" & DatePart("M", Now), 2) & Right("0" & DatePart("D", Now), 2) 
name = Tdate & "_XYZ_Report.xlsx"
filedate = DatePart("YYYY" , Now)& Mdate & DayDate
NewReport = fldrM & name
Logfilename="C:\Log Files\XYZ" & filedate & ".txt"
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Logfilename, 8, True)
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
Set ofolder = fso.getfolder(FldrM)
i = 0
For each f in ofolder.files
    If f.name = name then
        i = i + 1
    end if
Next        
    If i > 0 then
        WScript.Echo "File exists; please delete and try again"
        myLog.WriteLine cstr(Now) & ":  " & name & " File exists; please delete and try again"
        
        attachfile = ""
        ArgList = "C:\AutoScripts\SOutlook.vbs ""XYZ_Error"" """ & attachfile & """"
        Set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        oShell.Run ArgList,1,true
        Set oShell = Nothing
        Wscript.Quit
        
    else
        fso.copyfile ReportFormat, NewReport, true
    End if
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set ObjSource = Objexcel.workbooks.open (NewReport,0,False)
For Each objConnection In ObjSource.Connections
   bBackground = objConnection.OledbConnection.BackgroundQuery
   objConnection.OledbConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
   objConnection.Refresh
   objConnection.OledbConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
Next
j = 1
    for j =  1 to objsource.sheets.count
        objsource.sheets(j).visible = true
        SName = objsource.sheets(j).name
        If SNAME="ABC" or SName = "DEF" then
                objsource.sheets(j).visible = true  
        Else
                objsource.sheets(j).visible = False
            
        end if
    next    
    objsource.save  
    objsource.close savechanges=True
    objExcel.quit
    set objsource = nothing
    set objExcel = nothing 
    myLog.WriteLine cstr(Now) & "END"
    myLog.Close
```

Can someone please help on this. So what happens is there are Query in excel connections. which does not refresh and just ends the code. I want the file to refresh those connections and then close it. Hope that might be little clear now. So when you open an excel go to Data-> Query and Connection -> there i have multiple Query defined which pulls data from DB.

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Do you get an error? What happens when you set breakpoints?

Comment: when my code tries to refresh it throws an error of line: 75 Char: 1 Error: Object Doesen't support this property or method:

Comment: And the code stucks at For each objQuery In ObjSource.Query. Please if you can help.

Comment: A `Workbook` doesn't have a `Query` property.